# Android: cannot resolve Firebase deleteUser()

Tags: android, firebase

I am following the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) but for

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUser(currentUserUid);
```

AndroidStudio says it cannot resolve `deleteUser()`.

My import:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `deleteUser(String userId)` method in FirebaseAuth. If you want to delete current user you are signed in, the correct implementation is

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().delete();
```

You can check [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth)